# Should I remove i386 packages?

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, 32bit

I am on Linux Mint 21.2 (Victoria) Cinnamon `amd64` on Intel 7700HQ, and since I now found out there are 293 (`dpkg -l | grep i386 | wc -l`) 32-bit (`i386`) packages left from previous years, I don't know if this question is clear, but anyway:

Should I remove all `i386` packages? If so, or at least the majority of them, how should I proceed in several manageable steps?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not. Just like 64 bit packages, these packages are subject to dependency management, and if they don't get uninstalled by an apt autoremove, they are a dependency to something else, or explicitly installed.